# Azure blob Storage is messing Image Quality

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I'm using Azure Blob Storage for adding an image. Quality of my image is altered for some reason in bad manner which is leading me to incorrect functionality.

Can someone put some light on it. how can I avoid?

```
CloudBlockBlob blob = _blobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(filename);
file.Position = 0;
stickerBlob.Properties.ContentType = "image/bmp";
stickerBlob.UploadFromStream(file);    //its just a Stream Object.
```

Code shared. I'm also mentioning the content type as well. I can download and see the image as well but without any ContentType ,also my logic fails on that image.

Comment: Can you describe the problem in more details please?

Comment: I'm uploading image file to blob storage using i.e. just converting file to to stream uploadImageFromStream. When i download that file from blob storage. my flow which was working just fine before I added blob storage part. I can download and see the image as well but still the quality of the image is compromised.

Comment: Please share your code. I am guessing somewhere during uploading/downloading process some bytes went missing because the code did not treat boundary conditions properly. It has happened with me a number of times as well.

Comment: I really doubt that Azure is recoding your image... When you create a small, executable repo code you will find that *you* are doing that inadvertently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Saving your images in .png format would be good. You may want to specify the compression levels for other formats (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882583(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
public bool UploadImage(Bitmap bitmap)
{
    bool success = false;
    try
    {
        CloudBlobContainer container = BlobClient.GetContainerReference("YourContainerName");
        CloudBlockBlob blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("YourBlobReference");
        blob.Properties.ContentType = "image/png";
        byte[] file;
        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            bitmap.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
            file = stream.ToArray();
        }
        blob.UploadFromStream(new MemoryStream(file));
        success = true;

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //Handle error here
    }
    return success;
}
```